# Confusion regarding limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I came across in my textbook that "if a function $f(x)$ assumes any indeterminate form as $x \rightarrow a$ then limit must exist as $x \rightarrow 0$".
But let us consider a function
$f(x)=(\sin{x})^x$.
As $x \rightarrow 0$, $\sin{(x)} \rightarrow 0$, also; $x \rightarrow 0$.
So I guess the function assumes $0^0$ form which is an indeterminate form which implies limit must exist as $x \rightarrow 0$. But if we look at the graph of $f(x)=(\sin{x})^x$
[image]

It is clear that left hand limit doesn't exist as $x \rightarrow 0$ which implies the fact that limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ doesn't exist. So where am I wrong?

Comment: Which textbook says that?

Comment: @Arpan I hope you have misunderstood what the authors of the textbook meant to say...

Comment: @Jose Carlos Smith I have a textbook which says so(an Indian book). If it is incorrect please explain what is actually going on here.

Comment: Rather post the exact context and also the link to the pdf of the book for that.

Comment: @PierreCarre may be I have misunderstood.  But I couldn't arrive at any other conclusion from what they have written.

Comment: This is a plot of $|\sin x|^x$. It is misleading.

Comment: Indeterminate limits do not necessarily exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $a^x$ is only defined when $a\gt0$, the same is the case here. When defining a limit, we check both the $LHL$ and $RHL$, and so here the $RHL$ is defined as $\sin{x} \gt 0$, so the limit exists. But for $LHL$ (i.e, $x\lt0$), $\sin{x}$ is negative and so the term is not defined. Hence the $LHL$ does not exist and overall the limit does not exist. To add, if it would have been $|\sin{x}|^x$, both $LHL$ and $RHL$ would exist.